# Invited to staff photoshoot, but I'm resigning soon

Tags: internship, ethics, part-time

I work part time two days a week. I've been invited to a staff photoshoot taking place tomorrow, on a day I don't normally work. In most cases I'd go, but I've got another job lined up for January, so I'll probably be leaving soon. While the interview went great, I'll only be getting salary details and potentially signing the contract later this week, so it's not a done deal yet.

I don't think it would be right to go to the photoshoot and then put in my notice almost immediately after - those photos will be used on the website for the next year. And I don't want to reveal that I'm getting a new job before I've even signed a contract. Should I just make up an excuse not to go even though I'll risk my boss being upset with me?

Answer (score 193, accepted):

> Should I just make up an excuse not to go even though I'll risk my
>   boss being upset with me?

No.

You are making far too big a deal of this. Just go, be part of the photo shoot, then give your notice once the details of your new job are formally worked out.

Comment: It costs approx $0.05 to cut him from the library of photos. :)
And group shots are always going to be outdated as soon as they're taken.

Comment: Any decent photographer is likely to take a picture of the background just after getting the equipment setup and prior to assembling the group.  This picture makes it trivial to "erase" people later.

Comment: For maximum effect, give notice *during* the photo. ;)

Comment: In our office it's kind of a game to look at group photos from a year ago and see how many people are not there anymore.

Comment: Yeah, bittersweet symphony and all that :)

Comment: @insidesin: _"And group shots are always going to be outdated as soon as they're taken."_ Nonsense. Our group shot was taken two years ago and the entire group still looks exactly the same. Perhaps your team has a daily turnover of staff, but don't put us all in your sinking boat ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit no sinking ship here. Most companies change very often though, companies with <50 people obviously would still be difficult but not impossible.

Comment: @insidesin: Not "always", then :)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere: Hah, as it happens, that's a personal favourite ^_^

Answer (score 39):

> so it's not a done deal yet

You answered your own question, *it is not a done deal yet*, therefore you continue to work this job as though the other will fall through.  Which of course means **you need to participate in the staff photo**.

Comment: I agree with your overall point, but not with the "need to". There are other reasons one might not want to appear on a staff photo.

Answer (score 2):

Since the request if for time outside your normal schedule you should have no qualms about letting them know you cannot make it if it will have an impact on your new job.

However the others are correct in that you must work this job as well as possible until the next is signed and delivered, done and dusted.

In either case you should also consider that both jobs will require that you put the same time and care into the last two weeks as you did in the first two weeks.